# Httpclient-4.5.2.jar setEntity showing "cannot find symbol" (JAVA - netbeans 8)

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to use some code that I got from a website that has sports data served publically via an API (http://developer.fantasydata.com).

The site provide some sample JAVA code to make the http request.  For some reason the setEntity method for the declared request (request) is showing a "cannot find symbol error.

```
    package epl.fixtures.test.app;

import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class EPLFixturesTestApp {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        try
        {
            URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://api.fantasydata.net/soccer/v2/json/CompetitionDetails/EPL");


            URI uri = builder.build();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
            request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "****************");


            // Request body
            StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity("{body}");
            request.setEntity(reqEntity); 

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) 
            {
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

The line causing the issue is the *request.setEntity(reqEntity);* line

Can anyone explain this to me please?  I have all the relevant jar files from apache added to the project libraries directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpGet does not have a setEntity method.
This makes sense, since the request body has no meaning in GET requests.

Only classes implementing [HttpEntityEnclosingRequest](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntityEnclosingRequest.html) have this method.

I don't know why the documentation uses it, but it seems to work when omitting those two lines (which look meaningless anyway). Code:

```
URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://api.fantasydata.net/soccer/v2/json/CompetitionDetails/EPL");
URI uri = builder.build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "****************");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

if (entity != null) 
{
    System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
}
```

Comment: so why did they put it in the code example?  Any idea's how I can fix it?

Comment: Their code seems wrong. I tried to look at older HttpClient versions, but none seem to have this method on HttpGet. See my updated answer.

Comment: Cheers Johnny.  I ommited the lines and then got an SSL error which I believe was because the url is https.  I removed the s and tried with http.  I received the request header when I did.  Thanks for your help.  I've emailed the company and requested that they review their code.  I think I need an SSL certificate from them and will try to learn a bit more about the HttpClient in the meantime.  Thanks again.

Comment: Johnny, sorry for the second reply, I couldn't edit the last comment.  At first when I changed to http I got an http 503 (service closed for repair).  So I waited a while and re-ran the program.  It retrieved the JSON data.  Thanks for your advice.  Really appreciate it!